# Divide the list into two columns (get_posts)

Tags: get-posts, list, columns

The function below lists posts based on custom field.

The result is involved in a list `<li></li>`. What I would like to do is count how many list items there are, then divide it into two ul's. Is there any way to split the result into two columns?

[image]

```
function article_series() {
global $post;
$series = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Series', true);
if($series) :
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'Series',
        'meta_value' => $series,
    );
    $series_posts = get_posts($args);
    if($series_posts) :
        $class = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\\040\\.\\-\\_\\\\]/i", "", $series);
        $class = strtolower(str_replace(array(' ', '&nbsp;'), '-', $class));
        echo '<div class="series series-' . $class . '"><h4 class="series-title">' . __('Articles in this series') . '</h4><ul>';
        foreach($series_posts as $serial) :
            if($serial->ID == $post->ID)
                echo '<li class="current-post">' . $serial->post_title . '</li>';
            else
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($serial->ID) . '" title="' . str_replace('"', '"', $serial->post_title) . '">' . str_replace('"', '"', $serial->post_title) . '</a></li>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</ul></div>';
    endif;
endif;
```

Function created by [justintadlock.com](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2007/11/01/wordpress-custom-fields-listing-a-series-of-posts)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator.

```
$posts = get_posts($args);
$html = '<ul>';
$limit = 5;
$i = 1;

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $html .= '<li>' . $post->post_title . '</li>';

    if($i % $limit == 0) {
        $html .= '</ul><ul>';
    }

    $i++;
}

$html .= '</ul>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: Great @rofflox. Modulo operation seems to have worked here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at the number of series posts and stick an end/start `<ul>` in the middle. Something like:

```
echo '<ul class="left">';
$series_count = count($series_posts);
$series_middle = ceil($series_count / 2);
for ($i = 0; $i < $series_count; $i++) {
    if ($serial->ID == $post->ID)
        echo '<li class="current-post">' . $serial->post_title . '</li>';
    else
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($serial->ID) . '" title="' . str_replace('"', '"', $serial->post_title) . '">' . str_replace('"', '"', $serial->post_title) . '</a></li>';

    if ($i == $series_middle)
        echo '</ul><ul class="right">';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Then you can use CSS to style the two lists to appear next to each other.

Comment: Thanks @Nate Cook, but there seems to be a bug, because it adds `<ul>` for each item returned,. Returned 3 results looked like this: `<ul class="left"><li>Result 1</li></ul><ul class="right"><li>Result 2</li></ul><ul class="right"><li>Result 3</li></ul><ul class="right">ul empty</ul>`.